# Inheritance and method overriding in Scala

Tags: scala, inheritance, overriding, dynamic-binding

When we have the following basic classes

```
class X {
  def f = println("X")
}

class Y extends X {
  override def f = println("Y")
}

val a : X = Y
```

I think I am happy with why we get

```
scala> a.f
Y
```

But then I don't understand why we then have

```
scala> val b : AnyRef = new Array(10)
scala> b(0)
<console>:9: error: AnyRef does not take parameters
              b(0)
```

since as far as I can tell `AnyRef` is a superclass of `Array` in a similar way to how `X` was a superclass of `Y`. If someone could explain this I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the API documentation for [`AnyRef`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.4/index.html#scala.AnyRef) you will note that it does not provide an `apply` method - so the error makes sense.

You can see the same behavior if you change your example to add a method to `Y` that is not available on `X`:

```
class X {
  def f = println("X")
}

class Y extends X {
  override def f = println("Y")
  def f2 = println("Not in X")
}

val a : X = new Y

scala> a.f2
<console>:11: error: value f2 is not a member of X
              a.f2
                ^
```